# XCode 8.3.1 visual memory debugger shows incorrect number of objects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-management, swift3

I noticed some weird behavior of the XCode visual memory debugger:

```
import UIKit

class Card {
    init() {
        print("Card init")
    }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        var cards = [Card]()

        for _ in 0..<3 {
            let card = Card() // (first run: Screenshot #1)
            cards.append(card) // (first run: Screenshot #2)
        }

        return true // Screenshot #3
    }
}
```

*Screenshot #1* shows correctly only one instance of the Card class:
[image]

However, *Screenshot #2* which is taken after the card is appended to the array, shows 5 instances of the Card class:

[image]

At the end (Screenshot #3), according to the memory debugger, there are 7 instances. 
[image]

Console log looks like this:

```
Card init
Card init
Card init
```

**EDIT:** Examples of the memory graphs for various instances of Card:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas why I see this behavior?

Comment: Where you are executing this code ? In my environment everything works as required. Print screenshot after loop ends.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk These are code snippets from my actual project.

Comment: Let me update the question

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk I got exactly same result

Comment: Hmm in my environment all reference counting is done right. I will try to debug memory from instruments.

Comment: Are you on Xcode 8.3.1 ?

Comment: You are right I test on new Xcode and receive same behavior.

Comment: Receiving the same issue in Xcode 9.2.